# Facebook Request Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, oauth

Is there a way to ask for more g + and Facebook permissions on the login?

I know there is the [Accounts.ui.config](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config), and I know where to check the [list of permissions on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/) and on [gplus](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/incremental-auth).

But how can I ask for additional information on my current login which is pretty basic.

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook( {/* I think is here idk */ } , function( error, result) {

     if(!error){

      console.log(result);
     }else{

      console.log(error.reason);
     }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See an example:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
        requestPermissions: ['public_profile,email']
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        sAlert.error('Something went wrong! -' + err);
    } else {
        sId.settings.onLogged();
    }
});
```

More examples: https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-s-id/blob/master/client/sIdSocialButtons.js